# Using bangla text (bengali language) in a kivy label

Tags: python, text, label, kivy

i want to use bangla text in a k@ Kivy label. but its not supported. it shows something that's not supported (showing something like box box)

```
<hello>:
    Label:
        text:"কাল"
```

also used

```
<hello>:
    Label:
        text:"কাল".decode("UTF-8")
```

but not working. can you please help?

Comment: It appears that you can use any language, as long as you can download a font that supports it. See the documentation [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#catering-for-unicode-languages).

Comment: i downloaded a bangla font and create a folder named font. put that font file in that folder.  i add font_name:"font/kalpurush". its working. but getting an error. i wrote text:"কালকে". but when i run that app the label shows " কালক্ে"  and for text:"শহরে" it shows "শহর ে".    and not showing any complex word like,,  text="আস্তানা মাস্তান"  it shows  " আসতানা মাসতান" how to fix this issue?

Comment: I can only guess that the `kalpurush` font does not support all the characters that you are using. Try different fonts (I see that there are many available for download).

Comment: aslo tried using "SuttonyOMJ" font. but same result

Comment: I am facing this problem till now. @ashikuzzaman did u find any solution??

Comment: You can find the solution for Windows and Linux environments for properly rendering Bangla (and other non-english) fonts in Kivy in the answers I have provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646050/kivy-isnt-showing-bengali-joining-character-properly/63668449#63668449