# Kivy isn't showing (Bengali) joining character properly?

Tags: python, kivy, bengali

Kivy Python does not support Bengali joining characters,Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Can any one please describe what is the problem? What can i do to solve it?

Expected Output:

[image]

Program Output:

[image]

Comment: This comes down to how the font renderer behaves. Kivy supports multiple font rendering backends, but I don't know the details of how they are (or can be) configured, or whether any in particular supports these features. You may have more luck getting help on the Kivy discord, as there are more likely to be people familiar with font stuff there.

Answer (score 2):

Appropriate text renderer is needed to handle bangla fonts (and other fonts with complex glyphs) properly. The text renderer pango has features like fallback, complex glyph processing among many other features. Kivy supports pango text renderer with limited features as of now. Currently this has been tested in MacOS and Linux. Below is the procedure to demonstrate installation of pango text renderer with Kivy and an example app showing correct rendering of bangla text. The procedure assumed that Kivy is already installed in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04).

1. Check with the following command if pango is already installed
   correctly:

   `pkg-config --libs pangoft2`

   if pango is installed correctly, then it would produce following
   output:

   `-lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype`

   Otherwise, if it produces no output, then it is not installed
   correctly. In this case proceed to next step.
2. Issue the following command and wait for it to finish the execution:

   `sudo apt-get update`
3. Next issue the following command to install pango:

   `sudo apt install libfreetype6-dev libpango1.0-dev libpangoft2-1.0-0`

   Again check with command in step 1 if installation is done properly.
4. After pango installation, Kivy needs to be re-compiled. For this first issue the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y \
       python-pip \
       build-essential \
       git \
       python \
       python3-dev \
       ffmpeg \
       libsdl2-dev \
       libsdl2-image-dev \
       libsdl2-mixer-dev \
       libsdl2-ttf-dev \
       libportmidi-dev \
       libswscale-dev \
       libavformat-dev \
       libavcodec-dev \
       zlib1g-dev
   ```
5. Then issue the following three commands sequentially:

   ```
   sudo pip3 install cython
   export USE_PANGOFT2=1
   export KIVY_TEXT=pango
   ```

   You may receive `Requirement already satisfied` message for `Cython` installation, which is ok.
6. Now uninstall Kivy with following command:

   `sudo python3 -m pip uninstall kivy`
7. And install Kivy with following command:

   `sudo pip3 install kivy`
8. Once Kivy is re-installed successfully, you can run the following example:

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_TEXT'] = 'pango'
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


APP_KV = """
BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: "সকালে"
        font_size: '48sp'
        font_name: 'font/kalpurush.ttf'
"""

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(APP_KV)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

The `KIVY_TEXT` environment setting may not be needed as already exported earlier. But this is to show how you can select the text renderer. You need to have the font file `kalpurush.ttf` (or any other bangla unicode font file) under sub directory named `font`.

The Kivy log when you run the program is as follows:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/kivy/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-08-31_9.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.1 Mesa 19.0.8'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'VMware, Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.40'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pango
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Please note that the Text provider is `pango`.

The output of the program:

[image]

So, the text is rendered correctly. You can test with any other compound bangla letters, it will render correctly.

For other platforms like Windows, the challenge is to correctly install pango. It may not be trivial to do so as there is no simple way I have found so far. May be pango needs to be compiled from source with it's dependencies.

Comment: Hi @amras 
I tried your method but received this error:

`[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked`

`[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes`

`[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.`

Answer (score 1):

In my previous answer I have outlined procedure to install and activate `pango` text rendered back-end in Linux. Here I will explain a working procedure to install and activate `pango` for Kivy in **Windows** environment. Following is the environment where the procedure is tested:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6.8 (64-bit)
- Kivy 2.0.0rc3

Following are the steps to be followed:

1. Create a directory named `src` in the root of `C:` drive and
   go to that directory:

   ```
   C:\>mkdir src 
   C:\>cd src
   ```
2. Run the following command to clone the `vcpkg` to the `src` directory:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
   ```

   You need to have [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) installed to run the above command.
3. Then bootstrap `vcpkg` and move to `vcpkg` directory:

   ```
   C:\src>.\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
   C:\src>cd vcpkg
   ```
4. Now run the following command to install `pango` (with it's dependencies):

   ```
   vcpkg install pango --triplet x64-windows
   ```
5. After successful installation of `pango`, download the source tar ball of Kivy 2.0.0rc3 release from https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/2.0.0rc3/#files and extract in any suitable folder.
6. Now go to the folder where Kivy 2.0.0rc3 source files are extracted and open the `setup.py` file in a text editor (preferably Notepad++). Search for the line containing `if c_options['use_pangoft2'] in (None, True)` and add the following block of code before that line and save the file:

   ```
   if c_options['use_pangoft2'] in (None, True) and platform == 'win32':
       pango_flags = {}
       pango_flags['include_dirs'] = (['C:/src/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include', 'C:/src/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/harfbuzz'])
       pango_flags['library_dirs'] = (['C:/src/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib'])
       pango_flags['libraries'] = (['pangoft2-1.0', 'pango-1.0', 'gobject-2.0', 'glib-2.0', 'harfbuzz', 'freetype', 'fontconfig'])
       c_options['use_pangoft2'] = True
       pango_depends = {'depends': ['lib/pango/pangoft2.pxi', 'lib/pango/pangoft2.h']}
       sources['core/text/_text_pango.pyx'] = merge(base_flags, pango_flags, pango_depends)
       import subprocess
       subprocess.call(["setx", "FONTCONFIG_FILE", "C:\\src\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\tools\\fontconfig\\fonts.conf"])
   ```

   This manual configuration is required as `vcpkg` currently
   doesn't produce `.pc` files for automatic population of compiler
   linking variables through `pkg-conifg`. Also as of now there is
   no `pkg-config` tool integration with `vcpkg`.
7. Add `C:/src/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib` and `C:/src/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/bin` to the `PATH` system environment variable.
8. Now Kivy needs to be compiled from it's source. If Kivy is already installed please uninstall it first. And then the procedure mentioned in the official kivy site can be followed - though I am listing here the required steps to be followed. Upgrade pip and wheel with:

   ```
   python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
   ```
9. Get [Visual C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/visual-cpp-build-tools/) and install the following components from the "visual c++ build tools" section: "Windows 10 SDK (version)", "C++ CMake tools for Windows", "C++/CLI support", "MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools".
10. Set the required environment variables:

    ```
    set USE_SDL2=1
    set USE_PANGOFT2=1
    set USE_GSTREAMER=1
    ```
11. Install the latest versions of kivy dependencies:

    ```
    python -m pip install Cython==0.29.10 docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2 kivy_deps.glew kivy_deps.gstreamer kivy_deps.glew_dev kivy_deps.sdl2_dev kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev
    ```
12. Now go to the root folder where the Kivy 2.0.0rc3 source files are extracted (where the ```setup.py`` file is located) and issue the following command to compile and install Kivy:

    ```
    python -m pip install .
    ```
13. After successful installation of Kivy, you can run the following example:

    ```
    import os
    os.environ['KIVY_TEXT'] = 'pango'
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.lang import Builder


    APP_KV = """
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "অল্প বিস্তর"
            font_size: '48sp'
            font_name: 'font/kalpurush.ttf'
    """

    class MainApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return Builder.load_string(APP_KV)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        MainApp().run()
    ```

    You need to have the font file `kalpurush.ttf` (or any other bangla unicode font file) under sub directory named `font`.

    The Kivy log when you run the program is as follows:

    ```
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\user\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-09-06_12.txt
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev" 0.2.0
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew_dev" 0.2.0
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2_dev" 0.2.0
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc3, git-Unknown, 20200906
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Python\Python36\python.exe"
    [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 185 symbols loaded
    [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer, img_gif ignored)
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 26.20.100.7812'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 520'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 26.20.100.7812'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
    [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pango
    [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
    ```

    Please note that the Text provider is `pango`.

    The output of the program:
    [image]

    The text is rendered correctly. With `pango` other non-english language fonts having requirements of font fallback, complex glyph processing would render correctly.

    There are other procedures for installing `pango`, like with `gvsbuild` scripts as mentioned in the official site of GTK. It has the `pkg-config` integration as well. But it doesn't integrate successfully with Kivy. The installation through `vcpkg`, as outlined in this procedure, is the only successful procedure I have found.