# How to change the kivy text render from sdl2 to pango?

Tags: python, visual-studio, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I need to change my text render in kivy python from sdl2 to pango text render or text provider how can i make it ?

Comment: Have a look at [environment variables](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/environment.html#restrict-core-to-specific-implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After insatlling pango, use this at the top of your file.

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_TEXT'] = 'pango'
```

Comment: i did this but there is an error that failed to get text provider

Comment: have you installed pango?

Comment: i installed pangocffi from github is that correct ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646050/kivy-isnt-showing-bengali-joining-character-properly

Comment: thank you very much i will look for all that

Comment: i made every thing in the above documentation but still not working

Comment: the correct thing that the problem is in install pango but i can't find any resources explain how to setup this can you help me with this ?

Comment: the link i sent in the comments explains it

Comment: i know i did every thing which is written in the link but not working yet and this causing a big problem for me

Comment: pangocffi is not enough, it is just a wrapper around pango, pango itself is a program that you have to install and make it available in PATH, on Windows/Linux/macOS is relatively easy, I couldn't find an easy way for Android